# How to understand the structure of 'capable' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, clauses, attributives

I am reading an article 'Izmir Province' on Wikipedia, there is a sentence that I could not understand.

> "The greater Izmir region produces 20% of Turkey’s wind power from
> **wind turbines capable of** generating more than 1,300
> megawatts (MW)."

The point is the 'wind turbines capable of', I think perhaps it is an attributive clause in which the copula 'are' to 'wind turbines' is omitted because of knowing that it means 'the wind turbines can generate more than 1,300 megawatts', but I am not very sure about my opinion to understand the structure of that.

May you tell me about your view?

Comment: You could say it's "reduced" from *wind turbines **which are** capable of [doing something].* But then again, you could say that ***wind turbines*** is "reduced" from *turbines **which are** of type "wind"*.

Comment: No, it's not some kind of clause, but an adjective phrase. "Capable" is an adjective functioning as head of the adjective phrase "capable of generating more than 1,300 megawatts (MW)", which is modifying "wind turbines". Although a different structure, it has the same meaning as the relative clause in "wind turbines [that are capable of generating more than 1,300 megawatts (MW)]."

Comment: @BillJ What is the sentence structure here that allows this? I learned that this is a reduced relative clause following the rule that if 1) a relative pronoun is the subject of a relative clause and 2) the conjugated verb is "be", both can be elided. Am I conflating two different rules?